# Weak and strong property implementation

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I want to better understand `strong` and `weak` pointers implementation, and i figure out assumptions, about how their setter methods would look like (correct me if i wrong please).

First, strong pointer, look like:

```
- (void)setObj:(NSObject*)Obj   // Setting Strong Obj
{
    //First, check either we trying to set old value again

    if (_Obj == Obj)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSObject* oldObj = _Obj;
    _Obj = [Obj retain];
    [oldObj release];

    // Set pointer to old "chunk" of memory, containing old value, 
    // assign new value to backed instance variable and release
    // old value    
}
```

That is my assumption of construction, that strong setter may look like. So, my first question is - am i correct in my assumption?

Second, weak reference. I guess, it should look similar, but exclude `retain`.

```
- (void)setObj:(NSObject*)Obj   // Setting Weak Obj
{
    if (_Obj == Obj)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSObject* oldObj = _Obj;
    _Obj = Obj; // setting value without incrementing reference count
    [oldObj release];
}
```

Is that correctly assumption, about how `weak` reference work?

Ok, one more question. Consider a situation like that (in Manual Memory Management):

```
- (void)testFunc
{    
    strongObj = val; // Retain count about >= 2
    weakObj = val; // Retain count about >=1
}

// Now strongObj lives in memory with value of val, with retain count >=1
// weakObj is destroyed, since after end of a scope (function body) it retain count decreased by 1
```

So, actually i want to know, whether `retain count`  decremented each time, when method that own variable finishes?

I know that question is familiar to many developers, but, i want clarification in that cases. Thanks.

Comment: The weak setter would not release the old value since it didn't retain the old value. Only release something you retained or created.

Comment: @rmaddy then how exactly weak implementation look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first and second Q I refer to @rmaddy's comment and Christian's answer.

> So, actually i want to know, whether retain count decremented each time, when method that own variable finishes?

First I want to be more precise: When you say "when method that own a variable finishes" you probably mean "when a local strong reference variable of automatic storage class loses its extent". This is not exactly the same. But it is what you likely wanted to say. ("A usual local var.")

In this case it is correct that the referred object is released.

But things are more difficult behind the scenes. I. e.: What happens if the local var (more precise again: the referred object) is returned? What happens in this case, if the method is ownership transferring or not?

The basic problem is that an automatic reference counting has to take edge cases formally into account, even in "usual" code things couldn't break. A human developer can say: "Oh, there is a very special situation the code can break, but I know that this never happens." A compiler cannot. So ARC typically creates very much memory handling calls. Fortunately many of them are optimized away.

If you want to have a deep view into what is done in which situation, you have two good approaches:

1. Read [clang's documenation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), which is more precise than Apple's by far, but it is more complicated.
2. Create a class in a separate file that implements the methods for manual reference counting (`-retain`, `-release`, …) and log the execution. Then compile it with manual reference counting, which is possible through compiler flags. Use that class in ARC code. You will see, what ARC does. (You should not rely on the results, because they are subject of optimization and the strategy can change in the future. But it is a good tool to understand, how ARC works.)

Answer (score 2):

Your strong implementation is correct.

The weak one is wrong. You are not allowed to release the value if you have not previously retained it. You would just set the new value without issueing memory management calls here.

Then again, that wouldn't really be weak, but assign. The special thing about weak is that the reference is zeroed out of the referenced object is deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to think about strong and weak references in terms of balloons.

A balloon will not fly away as long as at least one person is holding on to a string attached to it. The number of people holding strings is the retain count. When no one is holding on to a string, the ballon will fly away (dealloc). Many people can have strings to that same balloon. You can get/set properties and call methods on the referenced object with both strong and weak references.

A strong reference is like holding on to a string to that balloon. As long as you are holding on to a string attached to the balloon, it will not fly away.

A weak reference is like looking at the balloon. You can see it, access it's properties, call it's methods, but you have no string to that balloon. If everyone holding onto the string lets go, the balloon flies away, and you cannot access it anymore.